# Filtering pandas dataframe using column values of column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question about some code.

So I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. `df1` looks like the following:

```
name     irrelevant_data_1
Kate     'some irrelevant data 1'
Mary     'some irrelevant data 1'
Max      'some irrelevant data 1'
Ethan    'some irrelevant data 1'
Peter    'some irrelevant data 1'
John     'some irrelevant data 1'
```

And `df2` looks like this:

```
name    irrelevant_data_2
Mary    'some irrelevant data 2'
Max     'some irrelevant data 2'
Ethan   'some irrelevant data 2'
```

I need to filter `df1` so that it only includes the rows in which the `name` column is in `df2`. The final look of df1 should be:

```
name    irrelevant_data_1
Mary    'some irrelevant data 1'
Max     'some irrelevant data 1'
Ethan   'some irrelevant data 1'
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: No, because I need the output dataframe to look like I said. That solution only provides True and False values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `isin`.

```
df1[df1.irrelevant_data_1.isin(df2.irrelevant_data_2)]
```